What should our custom off-topic reasons be?
Stack Exchange now allows custom off-topic reasons+. Currently, these reasons are:

Basic financial questions are off-topic as they are assumed to be common knowledge for those studying or working in the field of quantitative finance.
Questions seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy are off-topic as they are unlikely to be useful to other readers.

I've also proposed one on there that might not be visible yet:

Questions about becoming a quant are off-topic because this site is intended for people who already work in the industry.

We can have at most three reasons. What should these reasons actually be?
+ This link is in the admin section, so I'm not sure if non-mods can actually see this.

I definitely like the first one about basic financial questions, since that's a catch-all for many of the questions we get here. I believe that the second one about developing a trading strategy can be covered by the first, so we really don't need it as a separate reason.
I'd really like the career one to be:

Questions seeking career advice are off-topic because this site is intended solely for questions about quantitative finance as defined by our scope.

